# SP 2013 List View Column Header Set CSS full-width background color with CSS

Tags: css

I need help to set the background of a list view column header but not just the ms-vh-div.
I need to set the entire column width background of the header. This code only sets the background around the text.

```
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName="Column1"]
{
background-color:#FFFF66;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to select a parent element in pure CSS.  The closest thing is that there is a [`:has()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) proposed for CSS4, but according to [this answer over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/988264):

> as of 2020, this is still not supported in any browser.

So, you are going to be stuck using Javascript of some sort (vanilla? jQuery?) in order to get that done.

Comment: Thanks Dylan. Interesting to know. Cheers!